# python: when can I unpack a generator?

Tags: python, args, iterable-unpacking

How does it work under the hood? I don't understand the reason for the errors below:

```
>>> def f():
...     yield 1,2
...     yield 3,4
...
>>> *f()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    *f()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> zip(*f())
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
>>> zip(f())
[((1, 2),), ((3, 4),)]
>>> *args = *f()
File "<stdin>", line 1
  *args = *f()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you looking for ['itertools.consume'](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)?

Comment: Sorry, I was more wanting to know how *Generator works, and where you can use it.

Comment: The problem has **nothing to do with** the fact that a generator is used. All of these issues are equally reproducible if `f` returns a list, or if a list is used directly instead. Instead, the problem is that there *has to be something to unpack into*. `*args = ...` doesn't work, but [in 3.x](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) `*args, = ...` (note the trailing comma) will put everything into a list called `args`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `*iterable` syntax is only supported in an argument list of a function call (and in function definitions).

In Python 3.x, you can also use it on the left-hand side of an assignment, like this:

```
[*args] = [1, 2, 3]
```

**Edit**: Note that there are [plans to support the remaining generalisations](http://bugs.python.org/issue2292).

Answer (score 5):

Running this in Python 3 gives a more descriptive error message.

```
>>> *f()
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

Answer (score 1):

The two errors are showing the same thing: you can't use `*` on the left-hand side of an expression.

I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen in those cases, but it's not valid.