# Train multiple connected neural networks with a single optimizer

Tags: pytorch

How can I jointly optimize the parameters of a model comprising two distinct neural networks with a single optimizer? What I've tried is the following, after having initialized an optimizer:

```
optim_global = optim.Adam(zip(model1.parameters(), model2.parameters()))
```

but I get this error

```
TypeError: optimizer can only optimize Tensors, but one of the params is tuple
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are generator you can control either with the [unpacking operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967819/python-when-can-i-unpack-a-generator) `*`:

```
>>> optim.Adam([*model1.parameters(), *model2.parameters()])
```

Or using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> optim.Adam(chain(model1.parameters(), model2.parameters()))
```